# Meaning of "На некоторых страницах метро"

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Здравствуйте,

I have a question about a sentence I am working on (see below). What I am a 
little puzzled about is the: "пункты на некоторых страницах метро." in 
the sentence: "Также есть государственные пункты на некоторых страницах метро."

What does this mean and is there a real life link?
Can this be translated into that the offices are located in some subway exits or entrances?
How would you as russian speaker interpret "на некоторых страницах метро."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an obvious typo there, it should be "на *станциях* метро" - 'at the metro stations', not "на страницах метро" which has no meaning at all.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Strictly speaking, "на страницах Метро" *could* have a meaning, if you're referring to http://www.metronews.ru

Comment: @Dmitri - Come on! What kind of пункты are there on those pages if to accept it's about a news site? Besides, there's no capital letter in the original text, and the names of mass media should be in the quotation marks.